# Dynamic generation of input fields based on other input field value

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to develop a feature where the number of input fields generated are decided by the number I input in other input field.
For example: If I enter 4 in my 'quantity' form field then 4 input fields for `serialNumbers` should generate below as list.

My HTML Code:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput type="number" formControlName="quantity" placeholder="Enter Quantity" (change)="somethingChanged()" />
</mat-form-field>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of quantity">
      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput type="number" formControlName="serialNumber" placeholder="Enter Serial Number" />
      </mat-form-field>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

My Component Code:

```
somethingChanged() {
    let quantity = 0;
    quantity = parseInt(this.form.get('quantity').toString());
    let i = 0;
    while(quantity > 0) {
        this.serialNumber.push();
        i++;
    }
}
```

As I'm beginner to Angular, I don't get how to catch the `onChange` event without using Interpolation. Kindly suggest me a solution. Thanks.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/user-input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> try this simple example

```
quantity: any;
       somethingChanged() {
        console.log(this.quantity)
      }

      counter(i: number) {
        return new Array(i);
    }
```

> html

```
 <input  type="number" [(ngModel)]="quantity" placeholder="Enter Quantity" (change)="somethingChanged()"/> 
 <div>
      <ul>
          <li *ngFor="let item of counter(quantity)">
                  <input  type="number" placeholder="Enter Serial Number"/> 
          </li>       
      </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: The input fields I'm trying to generate for serialNumbers are supposed to be displayed as list and the quantity is just a number, not a json object. If I enter 2, two input fields should generate below the quantity input. @ORBIT

Comment: its genarating exact thing what you want check it

Answer (score 1):

Although your question is not clear, I think you need to get a dynamic number of "serialNumbers" from a form. here is the html :

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" (input)="onNumberChange($event.target.value)">
  <ul *ngIf="items">
   <li *ngFor="let item of items; let i=index">
    {{i}}) <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="serialNumber[i]" class="form-control">
   </li>
  </ul>
```

and the .ts file should contain:

```
onNumberChange(numberValue) {  
 this.number = numberValue;
 this.createRange(this.number)
}
    createRange(number){
      for(var i = 1; i <= number; i++){
         this.items.push(i);
      }
}
```

Comment: Could you show me the declaration of items array? In my example, I'm having quantity named form field. Is items same as my quantity form field?